# How to verify an access token from AAD in a next ts api

Tags: typescript, next.js, azure-active-directory, jwt, access-token

I can't verify an access token from AAD, even though it is valid. The token comes from a Flutter client, and all the necessary steps to obtain the access token have already been completed. I just can't verify the token from my api.

What I'm trying to do is verify the token using the public key from https://login.microsoftonline.com/my-tenantID/discovery/keys?appid=my-appID, but it doesn't work. I also tried using my client_secret as public key, but I get the same result. My first goal is to verify the signature of the token, and then I will proceed to check other parts of the token. Here's my code.

```
import jwt, { decode, VerifyOptions } from 'jsonwebtoken';
import jwksClient from 'jwks-rsa';

const JWK_PROVIDER_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my-tenantID>/discovery/keys?appid=<my-appID>';
const client = jwksClient({
  jwksUri: JWK_PROVIDER_URL,
});

export default async function isValidToken(token: string) {
  const keys = await client.getKeys() as any[];
  const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true }) as any;

  const kid = decodedToken.header?.kid;

  const publicKey= '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + keys.find(k => k.kid === kid).x5c[0] + '\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----';

  const verifyOptions: VerifyOptions = {
    ignoreExpiration: true,
    ignoreNotBefore: true, 
    algorithms: ['RS256']
  };

  try {
    jwt.verify(token, publicKey, verifyOptions );
    console.log("nice");
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("bad token");
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  }
}
```

My log

```
JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
```

This is my endpoint:

```
export default async function controller(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    try {
        const a= await isValidToken(req.headers.authorization?.replace("Bearer ", "") as string);
      
        const { method } = req;
        const handler = handlers[method as keyof typeof handlers](req, res);
        return handler! || res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} Not Allowed`);
    } catch (err: any) {
        
        return res.status(500).send(err.stack)
    }
}
```

I'm a student and I'm new using next, any help would be great, thx

Comment: *it doesn't work.* - that's not a sufficient problem description. What exactly does it mean?  In your code you catch exceptions with `catch (err)`, but you don't even log the exception message.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have fixed it. Please take a look at it again.